# How to add reference to an existing column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following table that is migrated already in my Database.

```
class CreateHouses < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :houses do |t|
      t.bigint :owner_id, null: false
    end
  end
end
```

I want to create a new migration to update the `owner_id` field and link it to `owners` table.

I've previously tried a few, but they all failed. I tried the following but did not worked as well.

```
class AddOwnerIdRefToOwners < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    add_reference :owners, :owner_id, null: false, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

Comment: Your column already exists, just add a foreign key on top of it. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#foreign-keys

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thanks for the reply. May I ask where "top" should I place? Because we are not allowed to touch the existing migration file(**CreateHouses**). We want to do it in the new migration which is the **AddOwnerIdRefToOwners**

Comment: Yes, do it in a new migration. By "on top of", I meant that the column should be created first (which is the case).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev sorry its just my 3rd day learning rails (from laravel). I don't know exactly what you mean. I would appreciate if you post an answer, just a syntax would do.

Comment: Exactly as you have it in your question, but do an `add_foreign_key` (with corresponding parameters) instead of `add_reference`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve it through the [documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#foreign-keys). For the convenience of the future devs who will encounter this,

My format should be,

```
add_foreign_key :<table>, :<foreignTable>, column: :<column>, primary_key: :<foreignColumn>
```

I solved by the following

```
add_foreign_key :houses, :owners, column: :owner_id, primary_key: :id
```

I give credits to **@SergioTulentsev** for helping me out.